# Dash App - NavBar

Tags: python, html, navbar, plotly-dash

Has anyone had success creating and inserting a Navbar in their Dash app?

I have a custom css sheet for the other elements, but I understand I need to create the [horizontal navbar object](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_navbar.asp) in the dash dummy code before calling to edit on the css side.

Where would I insert my navbar object in a Dashful fashion? Or rather, the ul list and list of hrefs specifically?

Answer (score 4):

I put a navbar on each page of the app. I add it to the layout. like this:

```
layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Nav(className = "nav nav-pills", children=[
        html.A('App1', className="nav-item nav-link btn", href='/apps/App1'),
        html.A('App2', className="nav-item nav-link active btn", href='/apps/App2') 
])...
```

This is one of the children of the main div in my layout. Classes above are from [bootstrap.css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) The Dash HTML components are all listed [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-html-components/tree/master/src/components). I just figured this out myself today, so I am still refining the css.